# Significance of higher noise gain of op-amp for AC applications

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, power, circuit-analysis, analog

I am trying to understand the reason why the noise gain of an op-amp is being forced to a higher value while driving capacitive loads and designing for AC applications.

As shown in below schematic snapshot from 'Ask The Applications Engineer-25 from issue Analog Dialouge by Analog devices' , resistor RD is added to boost the noise gain of the overall circuit for driving highly capacitive loads.

[image: Ask the applications engineer-25 article from Analog Devices]

By designing the op-amp with a higher value of noise gain (noise gain -->∞ feedback value --> 0) makes it more open loop system as a smaller part of the output signal is now fed back to the input and hence lesser chances of oscillation at the output at the expense of amplified noise signals from input.

Is that the reason for designing an op amp with higher noise gain?

Comment: Please add a schematic of the circuit you are talking about.

Comment: @Andyaka . Please check.

Comment: Ronnie - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the original schematic image source name & link (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is essentially the reason. This technique tricks the op amp into responding to a higher noise gain with regard to stability thereby improving stability margins.

If you were to ground Vin and refer all the noise in the circuit to an equivalent signal source at the non-inverting input representing the noise you would have the circuit below. This works for either circuit configuration in your question.

[image: Noise circuit]

You should be able to see how RD appears in parallel with RG as far as the Noise Gain is concerned and the Noise Gain = (RF/(RD//RG))+1

Adding RD to the amplifier has reduced the effective value of beta, beta = (RG//RD)/((RG//RD)+RF), and since the loop gain is equal to Aol*beta there is a lowering of the loop gain response which can be seen on a Bode plot as having the effect of improving phase and gain margins.

This all happens whilst leaving low frequency closed loop gain unaffected.

However there are drawbacks to this stability improving technique.

1. Noise is increased because the noise gain has been increased.
2. The closed loop bandwidth is reduced. Bandwidth = GBW*beta and since beta has reduced in value there is a reduction in closed loop bandwidth. This can be understood by recognising that by reducing beta we are raising the 1/beta response on the open loop gain plot and therefore the 1/beta plot crosses the Aol plot at a lower frequency reducing the closed loop bandwidth.

As a last point, the op amp's input offset voltage can be viewed as noise because it too is multiplied by the noise gain to appear at the output but it is DC noise. Therefore by adding capacitor CD we can stop the noise gain being increased at DC thereby limiting the amplification of the op amp's input offset voltage.

Comment: great explanation.